ldlidar ros 2, colcon build error, pthread mutex init/lock/unlock not declared
So i am trying to use the LD19 Lidar from ldrobot with ros2_iron. I am following this tutorial: https://github.com/ldrobotSensorTeam/ldlidar_stl_ros2. When i enter colcon build in the console it runs to 87% and then fails. I am using Rasbian OS on Raspberry Pi 5.
The console shows this:
Starting >>> ldlidar_stl_ros2
--- stderr: ldlidar_stl_ros2                              
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp: In member function 'void LogModule::InitLock()':
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp:172:3: error: 'pthread_mutex_init' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'pthread_mutex_t'?
  172 |   pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_lock_,NULL);
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |   pthread_mutex_t
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp: In member function 'void LogModule::RealseLock()':
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp:180:9: error: 'pthread_mutex_unlock' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'pthread_mutex_t'?
  180 |         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock_);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         pthread_mutex_t
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp: In member function 'void LogModule::Lock()':
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp:188:9: error: 'pthread_mutex_lock' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'pthread_mutex_t'?
  188 |         pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock_);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         pthread_mutex_t
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp: In member function 'void LogModule::UnLock()':
/home/pi/ldlidar_ros2_ws/src/ldlidar_stl_ros2/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp:196:9: error: 'pthread_mutex_unlock' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'pthread_mutex_t'?
  196 |         pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock_);
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |         pthread_mutex_t
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ldlidar_stl_ros2_node.dir/build.make:132: CMakeFiles/ldlidar_stl_ros2_node.dir/ldlidar_driver/src/logger/log_module.cpp.o] Fehler 1
gmake[2]: *** Es wird auf noch nicht beendete Prozesse gewartet....
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:137: CMakeFiles/ldlidar_stl_ros2_node.dir/all] Fehler 2
gmake: *** [Makefile:146: all] Fehler 2
---
Failed   <<< ldlidar_stl_ros2 [12.7s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [13.0s]
  1 package failed: ldlidar_stl_ros2
  1 package had stderr output: ldlidar_stl_ros2
```


The problem is a missing include of the required header file for the functions mentioned in the compiler output. See e.g. pthread_mutex_init for the required #include.
This can be traced back to log_module.h from the #include "log_module.h" in log_module.cpp of the ldlidar_stl_ros2 project:
#ifndef LINUX
#include <windows.h>
#else
//#include <pthread.h> <-- uncomment this line
#include <stdarg.h>
#define printf_s(fileptr,str)  (fprintf(fileptr,"%s",str))
#define __in
#endif // ??????????????????????


Thank you very much for your response, im going to try that once im home from work

This solved the problem, thank you very much! <3
